# how to dual boot fedora 18 and windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, fedora, multi-boot

i just bought a new DELL Inspiron 15R laptop which comes with pre installed windows 8 64 bit. I got no cd or dvd for windows 8. i want to dual boot my laptop with fedora 18. Can anyone point me towards a step by step installation process. i am a total novice and i badly need Fedora. I read online that there were some technical hitches regarding dual booting with windows 8. I dont want to downgrade to windows 7. Please help.

Comment: First of all, maybe you should create a Windows repair disk in case something goes wrong when installing Fedora.

Comment: I have done that

Comment: have you thought about a virtual machine? you can install something like VirtualBox inside of windows and from there start Fedora (if you don't need it all of the time) - this would be a workaround for the complete thing with UEFI problems and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever installed any Linux distro or partitioned a drive? If not, I recommend you to ask someone for help. It's really easy to break something in the process.

First, prepare your disk - defragment some partition to get free space at the end and shrink that partition. Create new partition in the free space with GParted (for example using [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php))

Then install Fedora, but don't write GRUB to MBR (you'll install some replacement for it later):

[image: Disabling GRUB installation]

Click "Continue" and avoid automatic partitioning, disable LVM and choose "Standard partition". Instead, on the manual partitioning screen select your new partition and choose it as the `/` mount point. Remember the drive name. (for me it's `sda1`, for you it will probably say `sda2` or `sda3`)

[image: Manual partitioning screen.]

Continue installing Fedora. When installation is finished, run terminal from the Activities menu and issue those commands: (replace `sda1` with your partition's name)

```
su -c bash
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
grub2-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda1 --force
umount /mnt
exit
```

Now boot to Windows and install NeoGrub using [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/).

[image: Installing NeoGrub with EasyBCD]

Clicking the "Configure" button will open your config file. Add something like this:

```
title Linux
find --set-root --ignore-floppies /boot/tboot.gz
chainloader +1
```

Leave an empty line at the end and save the file.

It SHOULD work, but I haven't tested it - my setup is quite different.