# How to set default boot operating system

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, windows-8, boot

My laptop can currently boot off Windows 7 and Windows 8, with Windows 8 set as my default operating system.

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 off a USB Drive onto a partition on my hard drive, but when I boot up, it still boots in Windows 8 and I have no option to boot into Ubuntu.

If anybody could shed any light on this subject, it would be very helpful. If you have any questions or need some additional info, just throw me a comment.

Comment: Have you tried using your computer's BIOS to select the boot disk/partition?

Comment: In the BIOS there is only an option to boot off a specific physical disk, and not the partitions.

Comment: Can you boot off a flash drive, then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least three ways:

- Open Start screen and type `msconfig`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and go to the *Boot* tab
- Use console tool `bcdedit`
- Use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)

If you have installed Ubuntu and it's not visible on the list, you can add it with EasyBCD: *Add new entry*, *Linux/BSD*, select type *GRUB 2*.

If it won't work, install GRUB 2 to your partition boot record as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/549514/how-to-dual-boot-fedora-18-and-windows-8/549534#549534) (skip first two screenshots and use `grub-install` instead of `grub2-install`.) You'll find the partition using `fdisk -l` command.

Comment: +1 for msconfig option - no extra software needed.

Comment: In msconfig, I cannot find the Ubuntu Installation. There is only Windows 7 and Windows 8.

Comment: Should a Linux Installation, or any other Operating System show up in the Windows 8 boot screen by chance?

Comment: @Anton8000 - Add the option yourself.  Windows has no way of knowing about your linux installation.

Comment: @Anton8000 I've edited the answer.
@Joshua `bcdedit` is also bundled with Windows, but it's really an opposite of user-friendly.

Comment: Thanks, it is working now. Posted this comment from Ubuntu.
@Ramhound How could I add this option to Windows manually for future reference?

Comment: @Anton8000 - Just add an entry to the location of your Ubuntu installation.  The solution proposed by gronostaj basically did exactly this.  Best leave booting to Linux to loaders like GRUB 2.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all the help. It is all working out now.