# Can't choose between Fedora 18 or Windows 7 at startup

Tags: boot, partitioning, fedora, operating-systems

I've installed Windows 7 on my system, and made three partitions: one of 180 GB, one of 210 GB and one of 75 GB. I've made a bootable DVD with Fedora 18 from an ISO file and installed Fedora on the partition of the size of 75 GB. Nice and smooth.

Too smooth, because after rebooting the system, I received the alert that my Windows has been affected, but could still access it normally and couldn't notice anything different. I've rebooted the system again, but I couldn't choose whether to start Fedora or Windows, it automatically started on the second one.

Of course, the partition with Fedora can neither be seen under Windows, nor be chosen at the startup. So, how could I regain my Fedora-partition and make it work? (be gentle, I'm a novice)

**EDIT:** 
I've followed the instructions shown by [how to dual boot fedora 18 and windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/549514/how-to-dual-boot-fedora-18-and-windows-8/549534#549534), but it didn't work. At the startup it showed the following error message: Error 15 Can't find file find --set-root --ignore-floppies /boot/tboot.gz
What should/could I do?

**EDIT:**
I've reinstalled Fedora normally (with authomatic partitioning and stuff) and it went smooth. Really smooth. Note to self and others: Unexplicable things happen when Linux and Windows meet. Be prepared! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add GRUB to the Windows bootloader's menu. You can do that using EasyBCD, I've described it [here](https://superuser.com/questions/549514/how-to-dual-boot-fedora-18-and-windows-8/549534#549534) (near the end of an answer). If that's not enough, you'll have to reinstall GRUB (also described there). To find out how your drive is called you can use the command `fdisk -l`.

Comment: Please create a separate question so others can see it.

Comment: @Eszter You should create a separate question for that problem.  Please include the model of your touchpad in the details.

Comment: So, I've tried to complete the steps you've described, gronostaj, but when entering manual partitioning, I can't apply the changes of the mount point to the root, moreover, the name of it isn't sda1, sda2, or sd3, but "root" (my boot is sda5).

Comment: your description hasn't been very useful unfortunately, because I can't get the manual partitioning right. I think Fedora is not for me. Thanks, though. :)

Comment: Skip the installation part, only find out your partition's name with the command I gave you and apply the EasyBCD step, if it won't work then repeat from the GRUB installation step.

Comment: So, I've done everything you've desribed in your answer, it worked and everything, but when choosing at startup I had two choices: Windows7 and NeoGrub, I chose Grub, of course, and it showed the following error message: Error 15 Can't find file find --set-root --ignore-floppies /boot/tboot.gz